# Installing bluecloth - configuration options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bluecloth

I tried installing the bluecloth gem by typing

```
gem install bluecloth
```

But when I do that I get the following error message:

```
checking for random()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/cyrusstoller/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby
    --with-rdiscount-dir
    --without-rdiscount-dir
    --with-rdiscount-include
    --without-rdiscount-include=${rdiscount-dir}/include
    --with-rdiscount-lib
    --without-rdiscount-lib=${rdiscount-dir}/lib
```

What options am I supposed to provide?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to have markdown installed before I tried to install the gem.

run

> brew install markdown

then

> gem install bluecloth

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to install bluecloth 2.0.11 under Ruby 2.2.3. Turns out that Ruby 2.2.3 was too new. Going back to Ruby 2.1.5 resolved the issue.

Check your .ruby-version.